# Scaling RenderTarget2D doesn't scale SourceRectangles

Tags: xna, scale, xna-4.0, rendertarget

I develop a 2D match3 game in XNA. The core logic and animations are done. I use RenderTarget2D to draw the entire board. The board has 8 rows and 8 columns with 64x64 textures (the tiles), which could be clicked and moved. To capture the mouse intersection, I use SourceRectangles for each tile. Of course the SourceRectangles have same size as textures - 64x64.

I would like to scale down the entire board, using the RenderTarget2D, to support different monitor resolutions and aspects. First I draw all tiles in the RenderTarget2D. Then I scale down the RenderTarget2D with a float coefficient. Finally I draw the RenderTarget2D on the screen. As a result the entire board is scaled down properly (all textures are scaled down from 64x64 to 50x50 for example), but the SourceRectagles are not scaled, they remain 64x64 and mouse intersections are not captured for the proper tiles.

Why scaling the RenderTarget2D doesn't handle this? How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should approach this problem differently. Your source rectangles for textures are just that — don't try to use them as button rectangles, or you will get in trouble like this.

Instead, use a different `Rectangle hitboxRectangle`, which will be the same size as your source rectangle initially, but will scale with your game window, and check intersections against it.